# OnPropertyChanged not being triggered when BindableProperty is set

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble with setting the `BindableProperty` `IconName` in a custom `ContentView` in **Xamarin.Forms**. It is never set and stays empty. The `OnPropertyChanged` method is executed for every property except the `IconName`. When I change the type from enum to a string, it works as expected. What am I missing?

The `OnPropertyChanged` method is needed otherwise non of the properties are set and remain their default value..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Peripass.Mobile.Framework.UIControls.PeripassIcon"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
  <ContentView.Resources>
  </ContentView.Resources>
  <ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Image>
        <Image.Source>
          <FontImageSource x:Name="_icon" Glyph="" Color="Black" Size="20" FontFamily="{OnPlatform  Android=PeripassIcon.ttf#}" />
        </Image.Source>
      </Image>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Peripass.Mobile.Framework.UIControls
{
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class PeripassIcon : ContentView
  {

    public static readonly BindableProperty IconSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconSize), typeof(double), typeof(PeripassIcon), 26.0);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconColor), typeof(Color), typeof(PeripassIcon), Color.White);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconName), typeof(IconType), typeof(PeripassIcon), IconType.NuclearExplosion);

    public PeripassIcon()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IconType IconName
    {
      get => (IconType)GetValue(IconNameProperty);
      set => SetValue(IconNameProperty, value);
    }

    public double IconSize
    {
      get => (double)GetValue(IconSizeProperty);
      set => SetValue(IconSizeProperty, value);
    }

    public Color IconColor
    {
      get => (Color)GetValue(IconColorProperty);
      set => SetValue(IconColorProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
      base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
      if (propertyName == IconNameProperty.PropertyName) {
        _icon.Glyph = $"&#x{(int)IconName:X4};";
      }
      if (propertyName == IconColorProperty.PropertyName) {
        _icon.Color = IconColor;
      }
      if (propertyName == IconSizeProperty.PropertyName) {
        _icon.Size = IconSize;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <uiControls:PeripassIcon IconName="NuclearExplosion" IconColor="#EE4022" IconSize="85.5"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing has to do with the fact that `OnPropertyChanged` is only triggered when a property's value changes (**it is not enough for it to be set!**).

In your code you set the default value of `IconName` to `IconType.NuclearExplosion`. Later on, when you call the control you set

```xml
<uiControls:PeripassIcon IconName="NuclearExplosion" IconColor="#EE4022" IconSize="85.5"/>
```

which sets `IconName` to the default value, again... so its value does not really changes, and thus `OnPropertyChanged` is not triggered.

---

### WARNING

That being said, i have to mention that the "normaly" you would use bindings between BindableProperties and the counterparts in the view. For instance, you would bind the value of Color property in FontImageSource in your ContentView to BindableProperty IconColor. For details see the [documentation on ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview#define-ui).

Comment: @Tijl.Reynhout, i am gladd it helped you. I extended the answer with a warning. Please take a look and let me know if it helps you...

Comment: You mean like this on my FontImageSource Color="{Binding IconColor}" Because that doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: If you have doubts on how to do that, please post another question and i will be happy to take a look :)

Comment: I created another question about this topic :)